# Jenkinsfile select parameter set

Tags: groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

A question from a Jenkins beginnner.

Is it possible to create a kind of choice which sets multiple parameters for all stages? Currently I am only able to let the user choose each parameter value on its own.

**Code:**

```
pipeline {
    ...
    parameters {
        choice(
                name        : 'stage',
                choices     : 'DEV\nTEST\nQS\nPROD',
                description : '''
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>stage</th><th>nfs share name</th><th>swarm endpoint</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>DEV</td> <td>DEV</td> <td>swarmid1</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TEST</td><td>TEST</td><td>swarmid2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>QS</td>  <td>QS</td>  <td></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>PROD</td><td>PROD</td><td></td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                '''
        )

        ****
        SOME MAGIC SETTING THE PARAMETERS AS DESCRIBED IN THE DESCRIPTION
        ****
    }
    stages {
        stage("do something") {
            steps {
                sh '''docker run ... ${MAGIC_NFS_SHARE} ...'''
            }
        }
    }
}
```